# 'Use select' notation to specify multiple partitions of Exact Online data container

Tags: exact-online, invantive-sql, invantive-data-hub

I'd like to select an active partition in the Data Hub. Normally I would use the following statement:

```
INVANTIVE> use 1552839
2>
Exclamation itgendhb077: Error in Invantive Data Hub.
Database '1552839' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
```

That gives an error. I noticed when I use the alias for my Exact Online Connection it does work so:

```
INVANTIVE> use 1552839@eol
2>
itgendhb018: 0 Rows Affected (111 ms)
```

But I'd like to do the following, selecting the divisions I want from a SQL table, that doesn't work:

```
use select division_code from dc.rs.selected_admins@sql
```

An alternative doesn't work as well:

```
INVANTIVE> use select code from systemdivisions@eol sd inner join dc.rs.selected_admins@sql sa on sd.code = sa.division_code
2>
Exclamation itgendhb077: Error in Invantive Data Hub.
Database '1552839' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
```

Comment: Are you using a distributed database with two or more data connectors by coincidence? Can you include relevant part of settings.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the alias is not specified, the first connected data container in terms of "sortingorder" is addressed. Given the type of error message, that is probably a SQL Server database.

Assuming that you are looking for a way to specify the partitions in a specific data container, the best approach is to use:

```
use select code partitioncode, 'eol' datacontaineralias from ...
```

This is identical to taking the outcome of:

```
select 'use ' || lst from ( select listagg(code || '@' || eol') lst from ... )
```

and executing that one.

Of course, when you have multiple data containers connected like Exact Online Belgium, the Netherlands and Loket and Nmbrs, you can provide them all in one `use` statement.