# Restrict list of employees in NMBRS to just a few companies

Tags: invantive-sql, invantive-control, nmbrs

I am creating a report on sick leave on nmbrs.nl using Invantive SQL.

By default this query retrieves data across all companies:

```
select *
from   employees emp
join   employeeabsence(emp.id)
```

This takes an enormous amount of time since for each company a SOAP request is done, plus one SOAP request per employee to retrieve the absence.

Is there an efficient way to restrict it to just a few companies instead of thousands?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 'use' statement or select a partition which is actually a company.

With `use` you can use a query like:

```
use select code from systempartitions@datadictionary where  lower(name) like '%companyname%' limit 10
```

to retrieve the first 10 companies with a specific name.

Also see answer on [use with alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46159641/use-select-notation-to-specify-multiple-partitions-of-exact-online-data-contai) on how to also specify the data container alias when running distributed queries.